# Is there a difference between a for loop without increment vs. one with a non incremented variable?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, increment

In JS, is there any difference between the following two types of loops?

1. A `for` loop without an increment such as:

   ```js
   for (i = 0; i < 1000;) { // i will be changed inside the block
   ```

vs

2. A `for` loop with a variable defined, but one that is not being incremented? Like this:

   ```js
   for (i = 0; i < 1000; i) { // i changed inside block
   ```

I saw this strange construct in several Stack Overflow questions.
`i` meant to note the `i` variable changes, not that `i` myself changed something or that `i` have been changed in some way.

Comment: did you tried this by your own ? and see the differences ? Syntax are not even correct.

Comment: It's not incrementing in neither of your snippets

Comment: I believe all parts of the for loop are optional .. the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) confirm my suspicion

Comment: Having a single `i` as an expression is a [NOOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)), so no, there is no difference between the two. Given that it doesn't do anything, I'd personally omit it.

Comment: @Ivar you answered the question. If they decide to put it back up as a legit qustion please mark it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal the first is very common in the literature the second, as I wrote is found on this website. Both work. Both are not recommended syntax.

Comment: @pashute I don't believe your question is off-topic (and is definitely not caused by a typo or not reproducible), so I already voted to reopen your question 4 days ago. It now needs one more vote for it to be reopened. If you haven't voted to reopen yet you can do so. Otherwise someone in the [Reopen review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats) will have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances: no, there is no difference.

> The **[for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)** creates a loop that consists of three optional
> expressions, enclosed in parentheses and separated by semicolons,
> followed by a statement (usually a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)) to be
> executed in the loop.

The [three expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#syntax) (initialization, condition and final-expression) are all optional (unlike the semicolons themselves), so if you omit the final-expression (which is most commonly used to increment the `i`/index/counter) that part simply will not be used.

If you use an isolated `i` as the final-expression, then this will be evaluated after every iteration of the for-loop. But an isolated variable on its own usually doesn't have any side effects. The value wont change and the value that is returned by the `i` expression (the value of `i`) is ignored in case of the final-expression.

```js
console.log('For loop without final-expression:');
for (let i = 0; i < 10;) {
  console.log(i++);
}

console.log('For loop with final-expression:');
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i) {
  console.log(i++);
}
```

But that is all under normal circumstances. There are cases where it *does* make a difference, but you really should never encounter this in production-ready code.

```js
const target = {
  i: null,
};

const proxy = new Proxy(target, {
  get(target, prop) {
    if (prop === 'i') {
      return target._i++;
    }
    return Reflect.get(...arguments)
  },
  set(target, prop, value) {
    if (prop === 'i') {
      target._i = value;
    } else {
      return Reflect.set(...arguments);
    }
  }
});

with(proxy) {
  console.log('For loop without final-expression:');
  for (i = 0; i < 10;) {
    console.log("loop");
  }

  console.log('For loop with final-expression:');
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i) {
    console.log("loop");
  }
}
```

In the above example I used a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to be able to intercept all access to the properties of an object and I used a [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) so that every variable is treated as a property of this proxied object. As a result, when `i` is read, the `getter` of the proxy is called, and I increment the value of `i` every time this happens.

In `for (i = 0; i < 10; i)`, `i` is set once at `i = 0` and read twice in `i < 10` and the final-expression `i`. Because it is read twice, the `i` will be incremented twice, so the loop will only iterate 5 times. In the other `for (i = 0; i < 10;)` loop `i` is only read once, so the loop will iterate 10 times.

There are likely more ways to achieve a similar effect, but again you should really never encounter this in production ready code, so it shouldn't be taken into account when deciding if you want to keep the `i` in the final-expression or not.

Personally I would say that if you don't use an optional expression, then you should leave it out. Especially because when glancing over the code, `i` can be misread as `i++` which might confuse the reader. But in the end it is a matter of taste.